# Многократная отправка Ajax запроса

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Я не знаю по какой именно причине, при отправке одного Ajax запроса отправляется два или более повторных. Это может происходить, может нет.

Блокировал кнопку отправки до окончания запроса, думая что пользователь одновременно нажимает на кнопку отправить несколько раз, но увы это не спасло.

В чём может быть проблема и каковы действия для её устранения?

Comment: Сложно судить, не видя код

Comment: Обычный стандартный Ajax Post запрос. Не могу код скинуть, т.к с приложения пишу.

Comment: откройте инспектор -> js отладчик, поставьте точку останова, посомтрите при каком условии отправляется n-й запрос. Остальная информация после публикации вашего кода.